# windows 8 semantic zoom using javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have multiple list views in my project how to implement semantic zoom for the following code thanks in advance

```
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <div id="detailsSection"   style="width: 100%; overflow-x: 
      scroll;height:100%;overflow-y:hidden;">
            <table style="height:100%;">
                <tr>                       
                    <td style="width: auto; height:100%;" id="myDealsSection">
                        <table style="height:100%;margin-left:120px;
        margin-bottom:50px;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
           <td style="font-size: 17pt;font-family: 'segoe   ui';width:100px;
   height: 12px;padding-left:5px;"><span id="MyDeals">My Deals</span></td><td>
  <img id="dealsHeaderImg" src="/images/Arrow1.png" style="display:none;
  padding-left:5px;"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="width:auto;height:100%;vertical-align: top;">
                      <div id="homePageDealsList" aria-label="List of  this group'
   s items" style="height: 100%; width: auto;" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"   

  data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'single',layout: {type:WinJS.UI.GridLayout} }"> 

   </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>                       
                    <td style="padding-left: 50px; width: auto;height:100%;" 

  id="trackDealsSection">
                        <table style="height:100%;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: 'segoe ui';height: 

   12px;width:120px;padding-left:5px;font-size:17pt;"><span id="TrackDeals">Track 

   Deals</span></td><td><img id="trackdealsHeaderImg" src="/images/Arrow1.png" 

   style="display:none"/></td> 
                                </tr>
                           </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="width: auto;height:100%;  

   vertical-align: top;">
                                         <div id="trackDealsList" 

   class="trackDealsItemsList" aria-label="List of this group's items" 

   style="height:100%; width:auto;margin-bottom:50px;" data-win-

     control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'single', layout: 

    {type:WinJS.UI.GridLayout} }"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>

   </tr>

      </table>

     </div>
```

for this code when i implement semantic zoom it is not displaying any data .so how to resolve this issue.please..

Answer (score 3):

The listViews that make up the Semantic zoom must be the only child elements of the Semantic Zoom control.  Something like this...

```
<div id="semanticZoomDiv" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SemanticZoom">   

    <!-- The zoomed-in view. -->    
    <div id="zoomedInListView"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
        data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: myData.groupedItemsList.dataSource, itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate'), groupHeaderTemplate: select('#headerTemplate'), groupDataSource: myData.groupedItemsList.groups.dataSource, selectionMode: 'none', tapBehavior: 'none', swipeBehavior: 'none' }"
    ></div>

    <!--- The zoomed-out view. -->
    <div id="zoomedOutListView"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
        data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: myData.groupedItemsList.groups.dataSource, itemTemplate: select('#semanticZoomTemplate'), selectionMode: 'none', tapBehavior: 'invoke', swipeBehavior: 'none' }"
    ></div>

</div>
```

The way your markup is laid out, you cannot use a Semantic zoom on it.  Checkout out the [Semantic Zoom Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465492.aspx), [Guidelines for Semantic Zoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465319.aspx), and the [Semantic Zoom Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-grouping-and-6d032cc1).